Is there an R package for performing Phylogenetic Multinomial Logistic Regression?
I am performing a comparative study (across species) and I would like to test how a single continuous X-variable affects a single Y-variable which is ordinal (0 < 1 < 2), while controlling for the phylogeny. I would like to be able to test differences in both intercepts and slopes.
I already performed the analyzes in nnet::multinom, but I would like to control for the non-independence of the species. I could not find an R package to do that, or a pertinent literature.
Any help would be great!
I tried using phylolm but, as far as I could see, the package deals only with binary data (Phylogenetic logistic regression)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
